# Add new row with values from $_POST and another table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert a new row in a SQL table (using PHP) with data from multiple sources. Specifically, I want part of the row to have `$_POST` values and the other to have data that is in another table.

Imagine a table with the following columns:

```
topic_id, message_id, message, topicmessage_index
```

I would like the inserted row to have the `message` from a `$_POST` variable and the rest of the data from a `select` statement. So, I'm looking for a query that resembles this:

```
Insert into Table ( message, topic_id, message_id, topicmessage_index)
$message , Select topic_id, message_id, topicmessage_index from table2
```

Is this possible? If so, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking here. Could you post your PHP code and SQL query so we can get a better idea of what you mean?

Comment: sorry Kmeixner but I have not written the code or query yet. I am trying to find out if such a query is possible.

Comment: Entirely possible: INSERT INTO table (message,topic_id,toicmessage_index) SELECT '$message', topic_id,message_id,topicmessage_index FROM table2;